# Prove or disprove bound on chromatic number.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

I am not sure if this is true, since I can't prove it. Let $G$ be a graph with chromatic number $\chi(G)$. Let $D$ be the set of all vertices of $G$ with degree at least $\chi(G)-1$, then $\chi(G) \leq |D|$. I struggle with seeing why this is true.

If I assume that $\chi(G) > |D|$, then there exist at most $\chi(G)-1$ elements in $D$. Thus, there has to be a vertex $v$ with $v \notin D$. This element can only have up to $\chi(G)-2$ neighbours. However, this is where I get stuck on trying to prove this already, but I also can't seem to find a counterexample.

Comment: Is $k$ allowed to be any value? How is it related to the graph $G$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann My bad, I edited the question, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** I would start the same way you did; assume that $\chi(G)>|D|$. This means there are at most $\chi(G)-1$ vertices with degree at least $\chi(G)-1$. We will get a contradiction by showing how to color $G$ using only $\chi(G)-1$ colors, contradicting the definition of the chromatic number.

The idea is this; start by coloring the vertices of $D$ with $\chi(G)-1$ distinct colors, which is possible since $|D|\le \chi(G)-1$. Then, color the rest of the graph one vertex at a time, choosing, for each vertex, a color not present among its previously colored neighbors. Since every vertex not in $D$ has degree at most $\chi(G)-2$, and there are $\chi(G)-1$ colors available, there will always be at least one color not present in each vertex's neighbors. Therefore, you can color the rest of the graph. Contradiction!